# New to java, need to learn how to store multiple Doubles with the same name

Tags: java

I am new to Java and want to learn how you would store different values for a Double. My code asks the user how many times he would like to calculate an equation, each time entering different values. The program takes the numbers entered than plugs them into a formula and produces an answer. My problem comes with trying to take all the answers generated and totaling them, I have no idea how to do this.

```
double wt, rep, t = .0333333, rm = 0, lts;
String initwt, initrep, lt;

lt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "How many lifts would you like to calculate" ); 
lts = Integer.parseInt (lt);

if (lts < 0){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You entered an invalid number"); 
System.exit(0);
}

while (lts > 0){

initwt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Please enter your Inital weight" ); 
wt = Integer.parseInt (initwt);

initrep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Please enter the amount of reps" ); 
rep = Integer.parseInt (initrep);


/* I want to take each RM value, and store it, so I
can total it later.*/
rm = wt * rep * t + wt; 



JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Your 1 rep max is " + rm ); 

lts --;  
}

int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
"Would you like to see your total?", "Please choose one",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

/* I want to bring all the RM values and total them to display here */
if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Your combined totals are " + rm );
}
else if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: You have two options -- use an accumulator, or use an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store multiple values with the same name. You can use an array:

```
double[] doubles = new double[/* size */];
```

And then access it:

```
doubles[0] = 5.0;
System.out.println(doubles[0]); // 5.0
```

Or have multiple doubles:

```
double d1 = 5.0;
double d2 = 3.0;

System.out.println(d1); // 5.0
```

Or you can use a collection:

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

And access it:

```
doubles.add(5.0);
System.out.println(doubles.get(0)) // 0 is the index, prints 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an array or collection.  Here's how you would add it to your code:

Before the while loop, initialize your array:

```
double array = new double[lts];
```

Then, instead of this:

```
rm = wt * rep * t + wt;
```

You could do this:

```
array[lts] = wt * rep * t + wt; // reverse order
```

Or this:

```
array[array.length - lts] = wt * rep * t + wt; // normal order
```

The easiest way to access these in Java is with a for-each statement:

```
for(double rm : array) { /*do something*/ }
```

Or if you need the index of iteration:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    double rm = array[i];
    // do something
}
```